# How to find parent of the control using div id

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to find parent using div id. I mean using $("#btn").parents("divid"). Is it possible using Jquery

Comment: $("#btn").parent("#divid") if divid is Id then use #

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) it is possible. You can pass an optional selector as a parameter to parents method. Therefore your code could be like `$("#btn").parents("#divid")`

Answer (score 0):

As an ID has to be unique throughout the page, it should simple be:

```
$('#divid')
```

If you have several elements with the same ID, you have to change that and use **classes** instead. Then you can use [**`.closest()`**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$('#btn').closest('.divclass')
```

If you want the direct parent, use [**`.parent()`**](http://api.jquery.com/parent/):

```
$('#btn').parent()
```

(actually, only the direct ancestor is the/a *parent*, all the others are just ancestors).